# is there a way to change the image url before load in webpack

Tags: webpack

first all,it is a webpack request

suppose i have a css and the content is simple like this

```
body{
  background: url('$my_path$/images/background.jpg')
}
```

and my_path is a varible,and will be changed later

and i set a loader in config file like this

```
...
 loaders:[
     {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'url!my-loader'
            ]},
]
```

what i suppose to do is in my custome loader it can replace the variable to a specific path ,so later the url-loader can load the right image file correctly

but i don't know how to do

can anyone give a clue please

thanks

=======================

finaly i wrote a loader to work it out

```
module.exports = function(content) {
    this.cacheable && this.cacheable();
    var srcPath=loaderUtils.stringifyRequest(this,query.srcRoot||__dirname+"/src")).slice(1,-1);
    content=content.replace(new RegExp("%srcRoot%","g"),srcPath)
    return content;
}
```

and in the html,i add a prefix into the url,eg %srcRoot%/images/a.jpg

so far it is work

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual path name in css and resolve it with [`alias`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url('images/background.jpg')
}
```

Webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        images: "./actualPath"
    }
}
```

Comment: i vote you for your feedback,however it is not work for my situation.it looks the resolve is only work when you do things like require('images/background.jpg')

Comment: `require` in js and `url` in css-loader resolves in the same way. Not work how? Webpack cant find file?